# How to save an image to the database with a path file

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to save a picture into my database along with the path file. But what it does now is incorrect. It only saves the image into the database and not the entire image path. What's wrong?

I do the exact same thing with this code in another project and can't wrap my head around the problem here.

```
$userPic = '';
$date_time = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');

if(!empty($userLoggedIn)) {

    if (isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {
        $errors = array();
        $file_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
        $width = 1500;
        $height = 1500;
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
        $tmp = explode('.', $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
        $file_ext = strtolower (end ($tmp));

        $extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");

        if(in_array($file_ext, $extensions) === false) {

            $errors[] = "extension not allowed. Please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
        }

        if ($file_size > 8097152) {

            $errors[] = 'File size must be 2 MB';
        }

        if ($width > 1500 || $height > 1500) {

            echo"File is to large";
        }

        if(!$errors) {

            $userPic = md5($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . $date_time . " " . $file_name;
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "assets/images/profile_pics/" . $userPic);

            $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET profile_pic = ? WHERE username = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $userPic, $username);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo "Invalid Username";
}
```

Comment: [Consult the following on handing files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) and you'll get your answer. Tip: Assign a variable to your `move_uploaded_file()` function, as shown in the manual.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it has a value

Comment: You wrote and I quote: *"It only saves the image into the database and not the entire image path."* - You used the `$userPic` for the database, so yeah... it'll save just that but not the path. I said to assign a variable to the moving function and then use that variable for the query, not the one you used.

Comment: I just tried this `$profilePic = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"assets/images/profile_pics/" . $userPic);`

Comment: And now the database holds a value of `1`

Comment: Ahhh... sorry Brandon, my bad. See in the manual, it shows this example: `$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);`. Base yourself on that. So you could do something like `$file_path = "assets/images/profile_pics/".$userPic;` and use that variable in the query. Pretty sure that'll work.

Comment: That works now thanks. Will you put it as an answer ?

Comment: You're welcome Brandon, done as requested.

Comment: You should be using IDs as foreign keys, not things like `username` that can change and get recycled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign another variable that contains both the path and the variable for the image you used, and then use that variable in your query:

```
$file_path = "assets/images/profile_pics/".$userPic;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code:

```
if(!$errors) {

    $userPic = md5($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . $date_time . " " . $file_name;
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"assets/images/profile_pics/" . $userPic);
    $imag_path = "assets/images/profile_pics/" . $userPic;
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET profile_pic = ? WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $imag_path, $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Try this:

You save only the new image name, not path.